# Unable to call each on a lockstep range containing 2 or more ranges

Tags: d

http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/76c79f1f12ab

```
void main(){
  import std.container;
  import std.stdio;
  import std.algorithm.iteration;
  import std.range;
  Array!int ai = [1,2,3,4];
  Array!int ai1 = [1,2,3,4];
  Array!int ai2 = [1,2,3,4];

  auto arange = lockstep(ai[],ai1[]);
  arange.each!((a,b) => writeln(a, b));

  auto arange2 = lockstep(ai[],ai1[],ai2[]);
  arange2.each!((a,b,c) => writeln(a, b, c));
}
```

> Error: template std.algorithm.iteration.each cannot deduce function
>   from argument types !((a, b, c) => writeln(a, b,
>   c))(Lockstep!(RangeT!(Array!int), RangeT!(Array!int),
>   RangeT!(Array!int))), candidates are:
>   /opt/compilers/dmd2/include/std/algorithm/iteration.d(820):
>   std.algorithm.iteration.each(alias pred = "a")

`arange` works but `arange2` doesn't because the compiler is unable to deduce the the function. The error even comes if I explicitly add the argument types.

Comment: It looks like `each` is hardwired to accept either a unary or a binary function, possibly because it still tries to support the string-style lambdas (`.each!"a++"`) using `unaryFun` and `binaryFun`.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15357

Comment: And another for `each`: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this issue is because of the following template constraints on each overload of `each`:

```
void each(Range)(Range r)
    if (isRangeIterable!Range && !isForeachIterable!Range);

void each(Iterable)(Iterable r)
    if (isForeachIterable!Iterable)
```

With `isRangeIterable` being defined as:

```
enum isRangeIterable(R) =
    isInputRange!R &&
    (isRangeUnaryIterable!R || isRangeBinaryIterable!R);
```

And similarly for `isForeachIterable`.

Thus `lockstep(Range, Range, Range)` cannot work with `each` as it only takes an unary function or a binary function (both of which take only a single range). This can't work with `lockstep` as the "range" (note the parentheses) it returns only defines a trinary `opApply`, which `each` does not support. This is why `lockstep(Range, Range)` works but not `lockstep(Range, Range, Range)` (as an aside, this only works by coincidence as the first argument is meant to be an index, which is supplied by `Array!int`. Your code does not do what you think it does).

This seems like a bug in the design of both `lockstep` *and* `each`; I'll file a bug report for it later. As for a workaround, for the time being use a regular `foreach` loop instead of `each`.

Answer (score 3):

`lockstep` doesn't actually return a range; it returns a struct with an `opApply` method, which `foreach` uses. This is because the `front` method for ranges can only return one value, but `lockstep` has to supply `n` values to the foreach loop. `each` apparently has some support for `opApply` structs (though the fact that the two-range lockstep 'range' worked is a bit of a bug; the first parameter is intended to be the current index).

Instead, you can use the [`std.range.zip`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#zip) function. This works exactly like `lockstep`, but wraps the results in a tuple, letting `front` return all the results. It requires that you unpack the tuples though.

Example:

```
auto arange2 = zip(ai[],ai1[],ai2[]);
arange2.each!(elems => writeln(elems.expand));
```

Comment: They are unable to use `zip` as it currently does not support mutating its `front` value.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain pretty well why this won't work with the current implementation of `each` in phobos.

Just for fun, if you really want an `each` that works with an arbitrary number of params:

```
void each(alias fn, R)(R r) {
  import std.traits    : arity;
  import std.string    : join, format;
  import std.algorithm : map;
  import std.range     : iota;

  // "arg0, arg1, ..."
  enum args = iota(arity!fn)
    .map!(i => "arg%d".format(i))
    .join(",");

  // "ref arg0, ref arg1, ..."
  enum params = iota(arity!fn)
    .map!(i => "ref arg%d".format(i))
    .join(",");

  // foreach(ref arg0, ref arg1, ... ; r) fn(arg0, arg1, ...); 
  mixin(q{
    foreach(%s; r) fn(%s);
  }.format(params, args));
}

unittest {
  import std.range;
  auto a = [1,2];
  auto b = [3,4];
  auto c = [5,6];
  auto d = [7,8];

  lockstep(a,b).each!((ref int a, int b) => ++a);
  assert(a == [2,3]);

  lockstep(a,b,c).each!((ref int a, int b, int c) => ++a);
  assert(a == [3,4]);

  lockstep(a,b,c,d).each!((ref int a, int b, int c, int d) => ++a);
  assert(a == [4,5]);
}
```

Unfortunately, you have to explicitly specify the types of your lambda's args. If you don't, it is a template rather than a delegate and `arity` cannot retrieve the parameter count.

Or you could just use `foreach`, but hey, then you don't get an excuse to do crazy stuff with mixins and templates.

Comment: Actually, maybe you can determine arity by looking at the range rather than the lambda...